# Bot Injecting Fake Field Into Form, Causing Error

Tags: validation, webforms, asp.net-2.0, spam-prevention, client-side-validation

A bot is spamming a form on my website, causing "A potentially dangerous request..." errors to be generated every few seconds. These errors are generated when certain characters, like '<', are posted back in certain elements, like form fields. This means that they need to be handled client side or else a "yellow screen" error will be produced before any server side validation has the opportunity to run. When the website produces and error, I log it in a database and send an email, so I've been getting overrun by the errors generated by this bot.

**What I Tried So Far**

- Google Captcha, modified to work client side.
- A hidden Honey Pot `textarea`, when if modified, uses JavaScript to remove the `OnClick` event of the Submit button. A check for this is on the `onchange` event of the `textarea`, and on the `OnClientClick` event of the Submit button.
- A Honey Pot timer on the Submit button, when if clicked within 5 seconds of the page loading, uses JavaScript to remove the `OnClick` event of the Submit button.
- I replaced the `textarea` fields with ASP.NET TextBox fields (rendered as `<input type="text" />`).

These methods all seemed to work temporarily, but now what's happening is the bot is injecting fake form fields. Here is an excerpt generated by our ELMAH error reporting:

```
<item name="ctl00$...txtMyTextBox"><value string="..." />
<item name="__VIEWSTATE"><value string="..." />  
<item name="method="><value string="..." />
```

You can see it's injecting `"method="`, which is not part of the form, and is then somehow thwarting the rest of the client side validation, and allowing the server side `OnClick` event of the Submit button to be run, causing the "dangerous" characters to be included in the post back, producing an error.

The "A potentially dangerous request..." error is well documented and I'm not looking to troubleshoot that, per se. I already know that it can be disabled, but I don't want to do that. I'd like to focus on the root problem of preventing the bot from spamming the form, specifically, how to handle situations when it injects fake fields into the form.

Lastly, I should note that the ELMAH error handling we use is run before `Application_Error(...)` in the `Global.asax` file, so handling it there probably won't be an option.

Comment: Is it coming from one and the same IP-address/hostname? If so, in order to fix the immediate issue, you should be able to implement som kind of checking for that IP/host when first arriving at the site, and if it's from that IP, send it off to some custom error page or similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, almost all of the IPs are unique.